# Two Body Problem with differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, celestial-mechanics

I have been learning up on the two body problem that uses differential equations to solve for a equation of a satellite relative to the planet. The two sources (linked below) both use different techniques, but I seem to be getting lost somewhere in a few places.

1. In the video, around time $12$:$30$, the accelerations of the satellite minus the acceleration of the planet is reduced to just acceleration. Why is this?
2. The other issue I am having is with the general solution of the differential equation found $\left( a+  \frac{G(m_p)}{r^3}  \vec{r}=0\right)$. This is because the two sources go different routes.

Can anyone help to explain and clarify it? What is the general process for solving the above differential equation?

Sources:

- [Orbital Motion: Two-Body Problem and Solution of Two-Body Differential Equation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yc3l1MEvkO0)
- [Astromechanics: The Two Body Problem](http://www.dept.aoe.vt.edu/~lutze/AOE4134/2differential_EOM.pdf)
- [Astromechanics: The Two Body Problem (Continued)](http://www.dept.aoe.vt.edu/~lutze/AOE4134/4OrbitSolution.pdf)

Comment: The links are missing!

Comment: Sorry! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yc3l1MEvkO0 is the video and http://www.dept.aoe.vt.edu/~lutze/AOE4134/2differential_EOM.pdf and http://www.dept.aoe.vt.edu/~lutze/AOE4134/4OrbitSolution.pdf is the lecture. its two parts